# Catchable fatal error: Object of class DoctrineORMModule\Proxy\__CG_

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I try to get results from query

```
$user = $this->getEntityManager()
                     ->getRepository('\ApanelUsers\Entity\Usercommon')
                     ->findAll();
```

but i have an error if I try to add to query Joined Column, without it I have fine results.
Here is a JoinColumt that I need:

```
/**
 * @var \ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_StatusId", referencedColumnName="UserStatusId", nullable=false)
 */
private $userStatusid;

/**
 * Set userStatusid
 *
 * @param \ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus $userStatusid
 * @return Usercommon
 */
public function setUserStatusid(\ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus $userStatusid = null)
{
    $this->userStatusid = $userStatusid;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get userStatusid
 *
 * @return \ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus 
 */
public function getUserStatusid()
{
    return $this->userStatusid;
}
```

Here is a view

```
<?= $user->getUserStatusid(); ?>
```

But I have an error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DoctrineORMModule\Proxy__CG__\ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus could not be converted to string in /home/xtadmin/localhost/panorama-hotel.local/www/module/ApanelUsers/view/apanel-users/index/index.phtml on line 27

Comment: Could you add the definition of `\ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus`. I'm not sure, but you might have referenced the wrong column. `referencedColumnName` should be whatever the foreign key points to (usually the id column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear you cannot echo whole associated entity you have to call one of its method, when you are calling `$user->getUserStatusid()` it means it will return you whole object of `ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus` entity so you can't echo whole entity at once using `<?= entity ?>`

One way you can just implement `__toString()` method in your `ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus` entity

```
class Userstatus{

     public fundtion __toString(){
     return $this->getTitle() // or you can use any other method to retrurn value
     }
// other properties with their related getters and setters
}
```

Another way would be

```
<?= $user->getUserStatusid()->getTitle(); ?>
```

But this will also fail because in `setUserStatusid()` you have allowed the status can be null so for second option you need to first check if its an instance of `ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus` then call its related getter

```
<?php

    $status = $user->getUserStatusid();
    if($status instanceof \ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus){
    echo $status->getTitle();
    }

?>
```